# What happens if I use a buildToolsVersion which is lower than the targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, targetsdkversion, target-sdk

I recently noticed that the gradle settings had the following configurations:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion = 30.0.2

    defaultConfig {
       minSDk = 33
       targetSDK = 33
    }
}
```

As noted, buildToolsVersion is not matching the targetSDK. But during tests and publications of the last months nothing bad has happened.

Now, I haven't modified anything related to gradle or sdk recently, however in the recent app upgrade publication (September 2023) app started to crash for some architectures when they tried to load native libs.

Could it be possible that incompatible buildToolsVersion affect how Google deliver bundle based apks or how libs are compiled and built?

The build version wasn't updated on error and now I am up to using 33.0.2 which should be the match for sdk 33.

Comment: Remove the build tools version it will take the version you have installed on your machine instead.

Comment: @NikolaDespotosk i don't want to do that because sometimes other processes in other machines use some of the build tools commands to inject or perform additional processes to the bundle or apk, so versions must match

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 or later, it will automatically pick the correct version to use. (You should only need to specify it explicitly if there's a problem with the default version)

See [SDK Build Tools release notes](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/build-tools)

Comment: yeah but that doesn't answer the question, what happens if I chose to use another one that is lower?

Comment: You really want to use the latest build tools (letting the Android Gradle Plugin choose it) to ensure you've got tools that match the version of the SDK you're using and have the latest bug fixes. As an example, the apksigner has undergone changes over the years in its APK signing schemes. If an older version of the build tools are is used, it wouldn't be able to use more recent signature schemes. available for later SDKs. (Generally speaking, older major versions of build tools aren't aware of features and optimizations available in newer Android SDKs)

Comment: And I would have to ask, is there a specific reason why would you want to use an older version? Removing buildToolsVersion from your build scripts means one less version number to update.

Comment: No, it was not intentional. But last app version suddenly started to crash on some devices, and it was a probable cause that build tools were not updated. However we already did some tests and it doesn't seem to be related.